# EmEditor Professionalで記号の数字での昇順、降順の並べ替え方法をお願いいたします｡

Tags: emeditor

EmEditor Professionalで以下のことをやる方法を教えてください。

たとえば以下のように記号と数字のついた行があるとします。
このときに、たとえば、▲の記号の数字の部分の数字順に昇順と降順で並べ替えるということはできますでしょうか？

このように数字の小さいものが自動で上に並べ替えられるという方法です。

**並べ替え前:**

```
▼とりつくろう▲920●920▽6458◆取りつくろう■
▼ねりこみゃ▲957●957▽3978◆練りこみゃ■
▼ぬぐいさっ▲1023●1023▽4098◆拭い去っ■
```

**並べ替え後:**

```
▼ぬぐいさっ▲1023●1023▽4098◆拭い去っ■
▼ねりこみゃ▲957●957▽3978◆練りこみゃ■
▼とりつくろう▲920●920▽6458◆取りつくろう■
```

Comment: 回答に対するコメントは、新しい回答として書くのではなく、私の回答にコメントしてください。また、質問が大きく異なる場合には、別スレッドの新しい質問としてください。既に書かれている新しい回答は、いったん削除することをおすすめします。

Answer (score 1):

1. [検索] ダイアログボックスで、`(?<=▲)\d+` と入力し、`正規表現` オプションを選択して、`すべて選択` ボタンをクリックします。

[image: EmEditor - 検索]

2. [CSV/並べ替え] ツール バーの `小さい値から大きい値へ並べ替え` ボタンをクリックします。

[image: EmEditor - CSV/並べ替え]

以上の操作を 1 回の操作で行いたい場合は、以下のマクロを実行することもできます。

```
document.selection.Find("(?<=▲)\\d+",eeFindReplaceRegExp | eeFindSelectAll,0);
document.Sort("N+",eeSortSelectionOnly);
```

マクロを実行する方法は、以下の通りです。

1. 上記のマクロを、適当なファイル名、例えば `SortNum.jsee` という名前で保存します。
2. EmEditor の [マクロ] メニューの [選択] から、保存したマクロを選択します。
3. 編集したいテキスト ファイルを開き、そのファイルがアクティブ状態で、[マクロ] メニューの [実行] (または <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) を選択します。すると、マクロが実行されます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。出来ました。

二段階、もしくは、三段階、四段階での一発並べ替えは可能でしょうか？

事例
▼だっこ▲1934●1934▽4616◆抱っこ■

▼ふくいん▲1934●1934▽6509◆復員■

▼れんぞく▲1934●1934▽3700◆連続■


このように▲の番号を第一の並べ替えとしてこの▲数字順は固定したまま次に二段階目に▽の順番を詳細に並べ替える方法は可能でしょうか？

整列後
▼れんぞく▲1934●1934▽3700◆連続■

▼だっこ▲1934●1934▽4616◆抱っこ■

▼ふくいん▲1934●1934▽6509◆復員■

場合によってはこれらの順番が5つくらい段階があることもあるかと思います。

この場合一度に並べ替えは可能でしょうか？
一度でなくても良いのですが可能なら1回で指定出来れば幸いです。

たとえば、「記号、もしくは正規表現に続く数字を段階的に並べ替える」という複数の指定項目を検索窓のように並べて一発で複数優先順位を指定して並べ替えできる方法です。
優先順位
1回目　(?<=▲)\d+　昇順
2回目　(?<=●)\d+　昇順
3回目　(?<=▽)\d+　昇順

というふうに1回で昇順、降順指定できる方法です。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 複数回に分けて操作できます。[カスタマイズ] ダイアログの [並べ替え] で `安定ソート` が設定されていることを確認してから、優先順位の低い順に上の操作を行ってください。マクロで一度に実行することも可能ですが、その場合 Sort メソッドに eeSortStable フラグを指定します。さらに質問がありましたら別スレッドにしていただけると幸い です。